# Allure Report generate NaN report in robot frameowork

Tags: python, robotframework, allure

When I tried to convert XML to HTML format in allure report, it throws an exception. Does anyone face this issue? How to resolve this exception. Also, the HTML report generates blank results.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHRpj.png)

Comment: Please click 'enter image description here' link to see the attached image

Comment: Please don't post links to pictures of code or tracebacks. Take the time to cut, paste, and properly format the information in the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use new [allure-robotframework](https://pypi.org/project/allure-robotframework/) plugin, it produce allure2 results.